# Using re.compile to classify unknown words in a text file based on their features

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Using Python 3, I have a list of around 14,500 unknown words and want to group them based on their features. I'm using `re.compile`, trying to get 5 dictionaries with the words that match each criteria, and a final list of words that don't match any criteria but some of the words that should've been grouped already are slipping through. Let me give an example:

Here are the `re.compile` statements I'm using:

```
import re

wordscaps = re.compile("^([A-Z]*)$")

lettersnumbers = re.compile("^([a-zA-Z][1-9])")

numbersonly=re.compile("^([^a-zA-Z][1-9]+)$")

titlecase = re.compile("^([A-Z][a-z]{1,})$")

longwords=re.compile("^([a-z]{15,})$")
```

The way I'm doing it is:

```
for line in testfile:
    if not line.strip():
        continue
    part=line.strip().split("\t")
    if part[1] in UNK_words:
        #print(part[1])
        unk_word_tags[part[1]]={part[2]:1}
        if wordscaps.match(part[1]):
            unk2dict[part[1]]=part[2]

        elif lettersnumbers.match(part[1]):
            unk3dict[part[1]]=part[2]  

        elif numbersonly.match(part[1]):
            unk4dict[part[1]]=part[2]

        elif titlecase.match(part[1]):
            unk5dict[part[1]]=part[2]

        elif longwords.match(part[1]):
            unk6dict[part[1]]=part[2]

        else:
            unkdict[part[1]]=part[2]
```

but in my final `unkdict` I'm getting words like:

```
'23390','4400','HS2NF5','IS1112C','vA33delta','Cbf5p','Grin2c'
```

I'm just wondering if there's something wrong with how my `re.compile` statement is put.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined your regex with the following logic : what_I_dont_want, what_i_want.
This does not work because it first expect a character matching what you do not want and then characters matching what you want. You only need to define what you want like that: (Add 0 to number I think)

```
wordscaps = re.compile("^([A-Z]*)$")

lettersnumbers = re.compile("^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)")

numbersonly=re.compile("^([0-9]+)$")

titlecase = re.compile("^([A-Z][a-z]{1,})$")

longwords=re.compile("^([a-z]{15,})$")
```

Comment: Thanks! this helped but for the "lettersnumbers" compiler, it ended up taking everything, regardless if it had a number or not. can you think of another way that will only take letters and numbers, not just letters?

Comment: I think it was because of the '\*' instead of a '+'. '*' match for 0 to infinite occurence so yes it was matching everything.